# No sound in headphones in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones

My headphones with built-in microphone don't work. System doesn't recognize my headphones for listening to audio, but it recognizes my headphones' microphone for speech.

My sound settings screenshots:

[image: Playback settings]

[image: Recording settings]

It enabled only speakers.

I installed Realtek drivers, but it didn't work. My headphones are Genius HS-300N, and my OS is Windows 7. Everything works fine on Ubuntu. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is it a laptop or desktop? What's the motherboard/laptop model? If it's a desktop, are you using the front panel sockets?

Comment: yes it is desktop and I use front sockets, back sockets are connected with speakers.

Comment: That Ubuntu thing is very important, I've added it to your question. Do speakers work on Windows? What happens if you unplug them and plug the headphones with the front socket? Do speakers work through front socket?

Comment: I tried, what you said. Connected speakers to front socket, headphones to back socket. Now speakers doesn't work, but headphones work. And Thanks for Edit! ;)

Comment: And what happens if nothing is connected to the back socket?

Comment: nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect both the 3.5mm connectors of your headphone to the appropriate jacks on your computer? You may have connected the microphone cord (pink) and hence, the microphone appeared. You need to connect the other one too if you haven't.

Comment: Yeah, Google Image Search tells me the Genius HS-300N headset has a green and a pink plug.

Comment: yes, I connected correctly, I sure. It works fine with my Ubuntu, but in Windows not.